# Write linux output to a specific column/row in an XLS or CSV file

Tags: linux, csv, output, row

I need to SSH into a Cisco device with ansible and get the output of a command I gave:

Ansible command:

```
ansible 10.1.1.10 -m raw -a 'show ip route' -u david -k
```

After this command is given out this is my output:

```
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      7.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C        7.7.7.7 is directly connected, Loopback1
      8.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C        8.8.8.8 is directly connected, Loopback2
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        10.1.1.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
L        10.1.1.10/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0Shared connection to 10.1.1.10 closed.
```

I would need to take this output and put it into an excel file, but the twist is: This whole output I have pasted above should go into a **single column/row** of an excel (or csv) file

(for example, this whole string should go to the **"B3"** colum/row of my file.

Problem is, everytime I send my output to a CSV file, the CSV file automatically splits it up (if a comma or anything is set in my output string).
Even if I ignore these things (commas tabs etc) with a CSV setup, still every "new line" in my output string is considered a new row in my CSV file.

Anyone has any solutions, how would I be able to add all the output to for eg. **B3 column/row** of my CSV or XLS file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're getting the output directly into B3, presumably you're copy-pasting?  If so, make sure to make the cell editable (a blinking cursor for text) and that you're pasting *into the cell*; instead of just selecting the cell and trying to paste the contents of your clipboard *onto the cell* (and then Excel tries to interpret the input and breaks it up).

If you can copy-paste as text, that's probably the best option as Excel will be able to properly handle any commas or quotes already in the ansible output.

If you still want a command-line solution, it's a little hacky, but...

Just wrapping your output in quotes should work, but only so long as the output doesn't have quotes itself.

I saved your sample output as output.csv.  Here's how it looks when I open it in Numbers (I don't have Excel).  You can see the data split across multiple columns and rows like you mentioned:

[image]

Here's a simple script which just adds a double qoute (") at the beginning and end of the output:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo '"' > output_with_quotes.csv
cat output.csv >> output_with_quotes.csv
echo '"' >> output_with_quotes.csv
```

And here's how that file looks when I open it in Numbers:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, actually, i have around 15 command to be ran against ansible and each commands output should go into a cell inside excel (One to B3 , one to C3 , one to D3 etc). So it would still be painful to copy-paste them and would still need to find a way to automate it, but atleast we are half way :)

Comment: Actually, I might have found a solution, there is an add-on for python called "PandaS" that would be able to do these kinda of things. I will dig further, we will see.